# Is it true $f^{-1} (B^C)=(f^{-1}(B))^C$? Is it true $f (B^C)=(f(B))^C$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it true $f^{-1} (B^C)=(f^{-1}(B))^C$?

Is it true $f (B^C)=(f(B))^C$?

I feel really confused about this. Can anyone tell me whether it is true and why?
Thanks so much!

Comment: Is your "$B^C$" supposed to mean the complement of $B$?

Comment: For your second equality, think about $f(x) = x^2$ on the reals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f^{-1}(B^C) = (f^{-1}(B))^C$: the set $f^{-1}(B^c)$ consists of all elements in the domain that do not map to $B$, which is precisely what $(f^{-1}(B))^C$ is.

On the other hand, in general $f(B^C) \ne (f(B))^C$. Let $f:\{0,1\} \to \{2\}$ be defined by $f(0)=f(1)=2$, and let $B=\{0\}$. Then $f(B^C)=\{2\}$ and $(f(B))^C=\varnothing$.

However, if $f$ is bijective, then the second statement *does* hold.

Answer (score 0):

the first one is always true, the elements that don't map to $B$ are the same elements that map to the complement of $B$.

the second one is true if and only if the function is bijective.

If the function is not surjective there is an element in the co-domain $z$ that is never mapped. Take any set $A$ in the domain. Then $z$ is in $f(A)^c$, while not in $f(A^c)$

If the function is not injective suppose $f(x)=f(y)=2$ , then $f(\{x\})^c $does not contain $w$, while $f(\{x\}^c)$ does contain $w$ since $y$ is there.

So a function satisfying the second must be bijective. If the map is bijective $f(A)$ and $f(A^c)$ are a partition of the codomain, so $f(A)^c=f(A^c)$

Answer (score 0):

The first one is true. The second one is not true, in general.

For the first one, if $x\in f^{-1}(B^C)$, then $f(x)\in B^C$, and thus $f(x)\not\in B$, which implies that $x\not\in f^{-1}(B)$ and finally $x\in \big(f^{-1}(B)\big)^C$. Everything implication goes in the opposite direction as well.

For the second, take $f :\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, with $f(x)=x^2$ and $B=(0,\infty)$.
Then $f(B)=(0,\infty)$ and $(f(B))^C=(-\infty,0]$,  while $B^C=(-\infty,0]$ and $f(B^C)=[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

$x\in f^{-1}(B^c)\iff f(x)\in B^c\iff f(x)\notin B\iff x\notin f^{-1}(B)\iff x\in f^{-1}(B)^c$

Showing that indeed $f^{-1}(B^c)= f^{-1}(B)^c$.

In general $f(B^c)$ and $f(B)^c$ do not coincide. E.g. let $B$ be the whole space. Then $f(B^c)=f(\emptyset)=\emptyset$ but if $f$ is not surjective then $f(B)^c\neq\emptyset$.